# Spark netty Version Mismatch on HDInsight Cluster

Tags: apache-spark, netty, azure-hdinsight

I am currently having an issue when running my Spark job remotely in a HDInsight Cluster:

My project has a dependency on `netty-all` and here is what I explicitly specify for it in the pom file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
    <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.51.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

The final built jar includes this package with the specified version and running the Spark job on my local machine works fine. However, when I try to run it in the remote HDInsight cluster, the job throws the following exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.netty.handler.ssl.SslProvider.isAlpnSupported(Lio/netty/handler/ssl/SslProvider;)Z
```

I believe this is due to the netty version mismatch as Spark was picking up the old netty version (netty-all-4.1.17) from its default system classpath in the remote cluster rather than the newer netty package defined in the uber jar.

I have tried different ways to resolve this issue but they don't seem to work well:

1. Relocating classes using Maven Shade plugin:

   More details and its issues are here - [Missing Abstract Class using Maven Shade Plugin for Relocating Classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63024448/missing-abstract-class-using-maven-shade-plugin-for-relocating-classes)
2. Spark configurations

```
    spark.driver.extraClassPath=<path to netty-all-4.1.50.Final.jar>
    
    spark.executor.extraClassPath=<path to netty-all-4.1.50.Final.jar>
```

Would like to know if there is any other solutions to solve this issue or any steps missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to ensure you only have Netty 4.1.50.Final or higher on the classpath